# Pesquisar por data em arquivo txt

Tags: php

Oii pessoal.. Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu preciso pegar valores de uma data até a outra em um arquivo txt. Ou seja, o usuário põe a data de inicio e fim, e são retornados os valores dessas datas. Se alguém puder me ajudar a fazer isso, fico grata! bjs

Ja tenho isso (parte relevante do código), aqui estou pegando o valor que me interessa no arquivo. Dai eu gostaria de pegar de uma data especifica, e o valor referente. 
Estou montando um grafico com esses valores. Dai o que preciso fazer: montar um outro com os valores das data que o usuario deseja.
Desculpe se estiver mal explicado rsrs

Uma linha do arquivo:

> 9/1/17,6:50:06 PM,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,VALID,920.221,VALID,920.221,VALID,920.221,VALID,0.0,VALID,2.4,VALID,-500.0,VALID,-500.0,VALID,-500.0,INVALID
>   - VALUE NOT AVAILABLE,0.0,VALID,811.697,VALID,811.697,VALID,811.697,INVALID -
>   VALUE NOT AVAILABLE,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID -
>   VALUE NOT AVAILABLE,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID -
>   VALUE NOT AVAILABLE,0.0,VALID,0.0,VALID,0.0,VALID,0.0,INVALID - VALUE
>   NOT
>   AVAILABLE,0.0,INVALID,360.0,INVALID,360.0,INVALID,360.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID,0.0,INVALID
>   - VALUE NOT AVAILABLE,0.0,VALID,34.947,

```
$arquivo = fopen('graficoItaguacu/arquivo.txt','r');
$dataPoints_umidade = array();
function processaLinha_umidade($linha_umidade){
    global $dataPoints_umidade;
    list($data, $hora,$tempSt, $tempAvg, $tempSt2, $tempMax, $tempSt3, $tempMin, $umiSt, $umiAvg, $umiSt2, $umiMax, $umiSt3, $umiMin,$pressSt, $pressAvg, $pressSt2, $pressMax, $pressSt3, $pressMin,$precipSt1, $precipPP, $precipSt2, $precipPPMensal,$radLiqSt1, $radLiqAvg, $radLiqSt2, $radLiqMax, $radLiqSt3, $radLiqMin, $radLiqSomaSt, $radLiqSomaSum,$radGl1St1, $radGl1Avg, $radGl1St2, $radGl1Max, $radGl1St3, $radGl1Min, $radGl1SomaSt, $radGl1SomaSum,$radGl2St1, $radGl2Avg, $radGl2St2, $radGl2Max, $radGl2St3, $radGl2Min, $radGl2SomaSt, $radGl2SomaSum,$radDif2St1, $radDif2Avg, $radDif2St2, $radDif2Max, $radDif2St3, $radDif2Min, $radDif2RD3SomaSt, $radDif2RD3SomaSum,$radUVSt1, $radUVAvg, $radUVSt2, $radUVMax, $radUVSt3, $radUVMin, $radUVSomaSt, $radUVSomaSum,$dvSt1, $dvDirAvg, $dvSt2, $dvGusDir, $dvSt3, $dvLullDir, $dvSt4, $dvSpdAvg, $dvSt5, $dvSpdMax, $dvSt6, $dvSpdMin,$chargerSt1, $chargerExter,$intSt1, $intT) = explode(",", $linha_umidade);

    array_push($dataPoints_umidade, array("x" => date_timestamp_get(date_create_from_format('m/d/y g:i:s a', "${data} ${hora}"))*1000,"y" => $umiAvg));
}
while ($linha_umidade = fgets($arquivo)) {
  processaLinha_umidade($linha_umidade);
}
```

Comment: E qual é o arquivo? Quais os formatos das datas? O que já fez? Qual foi o resultado obtido? No que ficou com dificuldade?

Comment: Poste pelo menos o formato do arquivo e o que você já tentou. Fica mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: O arquivo é txt, m/d/a, eu já processei o arquivo, estou tentando fazer um input para pegar a data de inicio e outro para pegar a data final, mas preciso fazer isso dentro do php. A dificuldade é justamente essa... Dai no que pensei: receber a data em uma variavel, e comparar com a data do arquivo, tudo dentro de um laço de repetição.

Comment: Ainda assim não é possível te ajudar. Edite sua pergunta com o formato do TXT e o código que já tem funcionando

Comment: Ficou mal explicado ne? kk desculpe.. Mesmo se não conseguir me ajudar, obrigada  pela atenção

Comment: Já resolvi o problema! se alguém quiser saber  como fiz me fala que mando aqui.